# GPGPU - Arithmetic intensity and caches

Tags: performance, gpgpu, bandwidth

I am studying theoretical stuff on GPUs used for scientific applications and I found this sentence:

> High arithmetic intensity and many data elements mean that memory access latency can be hidden with calculations instead of big data caches.

What does this exactly mean? Can be interpreted as a suggestion to avoid storing some precomputed results when programming for a GPU, but to compute them every time we run a function on the device?

E.g., suppose we have a code which performs a recursive loop in order to compute a long array, with tons of calculations in it. Besides, suppose we could precompute some partial arrays which would help inside the loop to skip some computations, even some which are not very expensive. According to the quote, should we avoid this but compute these arrays every cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPUs have access to different types of memory. The memory type you use to offer the GPU data to work with, and data to retrieve from the GPU when it's done computing is the global memory (for example, a standard GTX480 has 1.5GB of memory).

This memory has high bandwidth, but also high latency (around 400-800 cycles on a GTX480). So instead of precomputing things, storing it in global memory, and then retrieving it (causing high latency), you are better off if you compute it on the GPU. This way, you do not have to wait on memory to retrieve precomputed data.

If all the threads that are active at a given time (= warp), then this causes a high latency since these threads cannot advance because the data has not arrived. GPUs can calculate quite a lot in 400-800 cycles, so it's better to exchange memory fetches for computation.

That being said, you can use other types of memory that is available to you. For example, in CUDA, you have access to on-chip memory (shared memory), which is very fast and has very low latency. You can have one thread in a warp calculate something, store it in shared memory, and have the other threads use that value. So you move the precalculation to the GPU, and use on-chip memory to retrieve the precomputed values.

Answer (score 0):

GPUs are suited for data parallel computations. In other words, same instruction but on different data sets. At each cycle, the GPU runs a finite set of threads. But in the event, a group of threads (32 threads = warp) performs a load/store operation which would entail accessing the global memory and thereby incurring latency, another group of threads can be executed while the former group waits for its data. Hence, the key word *many data elements*. Latency tolerance on the GPU is done by having many threads at its disposal such that in the event of a long latency operation, another batch of threads can be executed.

However, I do not think it hints at not storing precomputed results in the GPU if they will be used for other computation. In the case for say Matrix multiplication wherein elements in the product matrix share common operands, there is a performance boost when these operands are stored in the shared memory because it is per multiprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Latency hiding is the concept that you can hide the load of data behind computational activity going on: you issue a request for data that you need in the future, and while you wait for it you compute something else. CUDA makes it easy to hide latency because it can switch so quickly between threads. So one thread issues a request for data, it blocks waiting for that data, but the core can immediately switch to the execution of another thread that does have its data.

For this to work, of course you need lots of computations to switch between. However, since data transfer is slower than data being used in actual computations, you need more computations than data loads for this hiding to take place. And that is the very definition of  computational intensity: a high ratio of operations per byte/word/number loaded.

I dont' think this has anything to do with precomputing, although you could consider upper the arithmetic intensity by recomputing certain partial results (from data still locally available) if that can save you some data loads from slower memory.